# HttpWebRequest GET request stops while processing

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, azure, windows-mobile

I am trying to make a GET request to my backend via a Windows Mobile app that I am working on. The request stops in between and doesn't get through. It ends with no error.

Here's my code:

```
public void LoginClick() {
    var myTask = LoginUser(email, password);
    string result = myTask.Result;
}

private async Task<string> LoginUser(string email, string password)
{
    //Declarations of Variables
    string result = "";

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://MYmobileservice.azure-mobile.net/api/loginuser?email="+email+"&password="+password);
    request.ContinueTimeout = 4000;

    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

    //Add headers to request
    request.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
    request.Headers["ACCEPT"] = "application/json";
    request.Headers["X-ZUMO-APPLICATION"] = "<SERVER-KEY-THE-APP-NEEDS>";

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync())
    {
        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            //To obtain response body
            using (Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    result = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Why does it end without completing? Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: You definitely shouldn't be sending the plaintext password over an insecure connection.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Other than that, do you see any reason why the request crashes while processing?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `async` all the way up. Here's how to re-write the event handler:

```
public async void LoginClick() {
    string result = await LoginUser(email, password);
}
```

I'm making the assumption that `LoginClick` is referenced by a delegate to a *Login* button's `Click` event. Notice that I decorated the method with an `async` modifier. Also, notice that the code is now `await`ing the `Task` returned by `LoginUser`. You might want to use the convention of `LoginUserAsync`, but that isn't required.

Wrap your code in the `LoginUser` method in a `try/catch` block. Set a breakpoint in the `catch` block to examine any exceptions thrown. You can look at the documentation of the `HttpWebRequest` *and related types* to see what exceptions they could be throwing.

Chances are that just using the proper *async* code will solve your problem because calling `myTask.Result` or `myTask.Wait()` will block the UI thread, which is your most likely problem.